# C# web requests interacting with LXD

Tags: c#, lxd

I am attempting to communicate with the LXD API from C#. In the command line, I can use

```
curl -s -k --cert lxd.crt --key lxd.key https://127.0.0.1:40/1.0/endpoint
```

to communicate with the API. I am looking to do this entirely in C#.

What would be the best way of making a web request like this? Or would it be better to use/make a cURL wrapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, it is possible to do this using RestSharp:

```
    RestClient client;
    public API()
    {
        client = new RestClient("https://127.0.0.1:40/");

        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

        var certFile = "lxd.pfx";
        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certFile, "(password)");
        client.ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection() { cert };
        client.Proxy = new WebProxy();
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        var restrequest = new RestRequest("1.0/networks", Method.GET);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(restrequest);
        Logging.Log(response.Content, "API", LogLevel.INFO);
    }
```